# Linear equations, how many solutions does it really have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math book says, a Linear equation has exactly one solution. Because $ax + b = 0$; $x =-\frac{b}{a}$. But I've solved many linear equations with multiple solutions before. 
(I'm not very good in math. Need help...)

Comment: A linear equation has exactly one of three possible amounts of solutions: 1, 0, or infinite.

Comment: Think of this as two lines $x \mapsto 0$ and $x \mapsto ax+b$, then the question is whether or not the lines intersect at exactly one point.  It is easy to visualise that if they cross that they intersect at exactly one point. It is easy to see that if they are parallel but separate then they never intersect and have no crossing point (solution). If they are parallel and lie on top of each other then all points are crossing points.

Comment: Are there equations that have more than one possible amount of solution?

Comment: @Joana Yes--these are called non-linear equations, such as $x^2 + 5x + 4 = 0$.  These are solved (algebraically) by transforming them into _linear_ equations: $x^2 + 5x + 4 = (x + 1)(x + 4)$ therefore if $(x + 1)(x + 4) = 0$ then it's solved if $x + 1 = 0 \rightarrow x = -1$ or if $x + 4 = 0\rightarrow x = -4$.  Therefore for the equation $x^2 + 5x + 4 = 0$ there are _two_ possible solutions: $x = \{-1, -4\}$--both found by transforming this problem into _two_ linear problems!

Comment: Can you show an example of a linear equation you've solved that has multiple solutions?

Comment: @Joana -- be sure you understand the difference between a linear _equation_  (which has a single variable and the variable is to the first power, like $ax+b=0$) and a linear _function_ (which has 2 variables, like $y=mx+b$ or $f(x)=5x+2$.

Answer (score 7):

If we assume that *all* linear equations have the form:

$$
ax + b= 0
$$

(which is completely valid and *should* be how we view linear equations)

then linear equations have either 1, 0, or infinite solutions.  It's quite simple if $a \neq 0$ then they have *exactly* one solution: $x = -\frac{b}{a}$.

On the other hand, if $a = 0$ then if $b = 0$ we have infinite solutions (any value of $x$ solves $0x + 0 = 0$) and if $a = 0$ and $b \neq 0$ then there are *no solutions* (there is no value of $x$ that makes $0x + 1 = 0$, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If we have $2$ unknowns, then the linear system

$$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = b$$

has, in general, infinitely many solutions. Why is that? Assuming that $a_1 \neq 0$, we write

$$x_1 = \frac{b}{a_1} - \left(\frac{a_2}{a_1}\right) x_2$$

Let $x_2 = \gamma$, where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, the solution set is a **line** parameterized as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{b}{a_1}\\ 0\end{bmatrix} + \gamma \begin{bmatrix} - \frac{a_2}{a_1}\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: But in a linear system (in the sense of the OP's question) we have a single unknown--not two.  I get the want to extrapolate to many systems (which this definitely has an application)...once you start talking about a matrix with a zero determinant and being set to $\begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Jared With one unknown, only $0 x = 0$ has more than one solution, which is boring. I didn't want to obscure things, but who hasn't seen a linear system with two unknowns when plotting the graph of $y = m x + b$?

Comment: Whys is it "more boring" to have $0x = 0$ therefore $x$ can be anything rather than $x + y = 2$ and $ 2x + 2y = 4$ where $x$ can be anything?

Comment: @Jared Because $\mathbb{R}$ only has one direction, whereas $\mathbb{R}^2$ has infinitely many.

Comment: I don't understand why having "infinitely many directions" makes a problem more interesting--I don't even know what that means...it would seem that a 3D problem is "more interesting" than a 2D problem and thus a "4D" problem more interesting than a "3D" problem, etc.

Comment: If you want to make the "matrix" argument, it's quite easy to make from the original point: $Ax  = b$.  If $\det(A) = 0$ then there are infinite solutions if $b = 0$ or $0$ solutions if $b \neq 0$--otherwise, if $\det(A) \neq 0$ there is exactly _one_ solution.

Comment: @Jared Consider a function from linear systems $(A,b)$ to number of solutions $\{0,1,\infty\}$. The pre-image of $\{0\}$ is not a singleton when there is more than one unknown.

Comment: I don't see how a discrete system could be described as linear.  Since it requires that $f(x + a) = f(x) + f(a)$.  There's no way to map $(A, b)$ to $\{0, 1, \infty\}$ such that that could be a linear map (you'll have to be more specific for me to understand your argument, sorry--and that's a legitimate sorry--perhaps I am misunderstanding your notation).

Comment: @Jared I never claimed the function I mentioned in the previous comment is linear.